# Writing Multiple CSV files from dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm trying to load a monthly mastercard statement into a csv file for my business using python. then create a program to send an in-house itemized statement to send to each user based on their spending for the month. How would I write multiple .csv files based on their card number.

I'm new to programming so i'm not entirely sure how to write to multiple csv files. I can do a single file but i'm not sure how to take the next step.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
df = pd.read_csv("/users/user/documents/data.csv")
df['Total'] = df.groupby('Card Number')['Posted Amount'].transform('sum')

body = df.groupby(['Card Number','Cardholder Name','Email','Total','Merchant Name'])['Posted Amount'].agg('sum')
```

when i hit print(body) the following information is displayed

```
cardnumber,name,email,total,merchant_name,posted_amount
0001,user1,user1@email.com,1531,merchant 1,1530
                                merchant 2,1531
0002,user2,user2@tmail.com,500,merchant 5,200
                               merchant 6,250
                               merchant 7,50
```

How can i write multiple csv files to be separated by each cardnumber or name? I'm relatively new to all of this, so if you need any more information let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `cardnumber` is unique and your dataframe is not too large:

Simply loop over all cards numbers and filter your `DataFrame` for a particular card. Group for each user. Then, save the output in e.g. `"Card Data for 0001.csv"`

```py
for cn in df.cardnumber.values:
    df_user = df[df.cardnumber == cn]

    # Do your grouping here:
    # ...

    path = "Card Data for " + cn + ".csv"

    df_user.to_csv(path)
```

Keep in mind, if your dataframe contains e.g. 50,000 card numbers, this code will create 50,000 files.